# Android - Facebook SDK 3 Error - remote_app_id does not match stored id

Tags: android, facebook

i've developed login with facebook in my application earlier it was working fine but now it is not working when i press login button , i can see dialog asking for user name and password but now i'm getting following errors , i did'nt made any changes in code , after google i found that it can happen when wrong key is generate so i h've generated and tried approx 5 key but none of them are working ,

i also found followeing alternate but didn't worked

```
      public void printHashKey() {

    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("your.package.name",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("TEMPTAGHASH KEY:",
                    Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }

}
```

Here i've `changed package` name but this is not working and i generate hash key using

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Admini.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64
```

Logcat :

```
06-29 10:23:51.219: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7532): Exception during service
06-29 10:23:51.219: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7532): com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: remote_app_id does not match stored id 
06-29 10:23:51.219: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7532):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:78)
06-29 10:23:51.219: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7532):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:107)
06-29 10:23:51.219: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7532):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponse.h(ApiResponse.java:208)
06-29 10:23:51.219: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7532):  at com.facebook.katana.server.protocol.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:266)
06-29 10:23:51.219: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7532):  at com.facebook.katana.server.protocol.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:27)
06-29 10:23:51.219: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7532):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:144)
06-29 10:23:51.219: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7532):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.AbstractSingleMethodRunner.a(AbstractSingleMethodRunner.java:16)
06-29 10:23:51.219: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7532):  at com.facebook.katana.server.handler.PlatformOperationHandler.c(PlatformOperationHandler.java:284)
06-29 10:23:51.219: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7532):  at com.facebook.katana.server.handler.PlatformOperationHandler.a(PlatformOperationHandler.java:185)
06-29 10:23:51.219: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7532):  at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:245)
06-29 10:23:51.219: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7532):  at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:51)
06-29 10:23:51.219: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7532):  at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue$3.run(BlueServiceQueue.java:191)
06-29 10:23:51.219: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7532):  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
06-29 10:23:51.219: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7532):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-29 10:23:51.219: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7532):  at com.facebook.common.executors.HandlerExecutorServiceImpl$ListenableScheduledFuture.run(HandlerExecutorServiceImpl.java:268)
06-29 10:23:51.219: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7532):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-29 10:23:51.219: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7532):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-29 10:23:51.219: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7532):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-29 10:23:51.219: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(7532):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

**Update :**
   But when i have changed my desktop and try to use same project with same key it worked fine . No idea what is problem.

Comment: Have you insersed the value of hash key printed in logcat to the facebook app..